# Parse TXT file with JSON strings as List<MyDataEntry>

Tags: java, json

I have a txt file with the following JSON strings:

```
{"id":1,"data":"abc"}
{"id":2,"data":"rbc"}
{"id":3,"data":"gbc"}
```

I read this file as follows:

```
    File f = new File("src/test/resources/jsons.txt");
    if (f.exists()){
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/jsons.txt");
        data = IOUtils.toString(is);
    }
```

Now I want to parse the content of this file as `List<MyDataEntry>`. This is the snippet code of the class `MyDataEntry`.

How to properly extract each separate JSON string and send it to the constructor of `MyDataEntry`? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
class MyDataEntry {
    private String id;
    private String data;

    public MyDataEntry(String rawDataEntry)
    {
        parse(rawDataEntry);
    }

    private parse(String rawDataEntry)
    {
        JSONObject rd =  new JSONObject(rawDataEntry);
        if(rd.has("id")){
           id = data.getString("id");
        }
        if(rd.has("data")){
           data = data.getString("data");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the file format? If you transform the file to valid json like `[{ "id": 1, "data": "abc"}, { "id": 2, "data": "rbc"}, { "id": 3, "data": "gbc" }]` you could use one of many different json libraries to parse the input (jackson, gson, ). You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to check the format of your json.

Comment: Do you mean efficient in terms of speed/memory or number of lines of code?

Comment: If you're using SimpleJSON (or GSON, or probably any other JSON library, then you should just be able to read your entire file into a JSON object and then iterate over array, q.v. [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) for more information.

Comment: @lippertsjan: I don't have a control over the txt file

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. You can use the [Jackson JSON](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to do that for you ;)

Example:

First you need to restructure your JSON (If you don't have `write` access to the file, read it line by line and construct your own JSON structure):

```
{
    "allData":[
         {"id":"123", "data":"some data"},
         ...
    ]
}
```

MyDataWrapper.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyDataWrapper {
     @JsonProperty("allData")
     public List<MyData> allData;
}
```

MyData.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyData {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public int id;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public String data;
}
```

To parse the file:

```
try {
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     InputStream file = getClass().getResourceAsStream("MY_FILE.txt");
     MyDataWrapper myDataWrapper = mapper.readValue(file, MyDataWrapper.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**

To parse from string:

```
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, MyDataWrapper.class);
```

Reference: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: Should `lexicalTokensConfig` be `List<MyDataEntry>`?

Comment: @HackerDuck sorry about that, I copied it from my repo:
https://github.com/amirbawab/EasyCC/blob/master/lexical-analysis/src/main/java/core/config/LexicalConfig.java
Check the update

Comment: How can I get an access to each separate MyDataEntry? As far as I understand from your example, you are reading a single JSON string `{...}`.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding restructuring the file, if I read it line by line, should I save this new file and then open it as you showed: `InputStream file = getClass().getResourceAsStream("MY_FILE.txt");`  ?

Comment: @HackerDuck you can store it in a string to avoid IO instructions. Example: `Staff obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, MyDataWrapper.class);`